# How to change the background colour of card view?

Tags: java, android

I tried to change the background colour of the `Cardview` once it get clicked. here am listing the notification history in `RecyclerView`. `Cardview` colour changing only on that time only. If I went back and open the app again means its not get changed. what I have to do ?

This is my adapter class

```
public class NotificationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static final String TAG = "DataViewHolder";
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<NotificationsModel> notificationsModelList;

    public NotificationsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NotificationsModel> notificationsModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notificationsModelList = notificationsModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.notification_layout, parent, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: ");
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final NotificationsModel notificationsModel = notificationsModelList.get(position);
        holder.title_news.setText(notificationsModel.getTitle());
        holder.notif_message.setText(notificationsModel.getMessage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationsModelList == null ? 0 : notificationsModelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView notif_message, title_news;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            title_news = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_news);
            notif_message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.notif_message);
            CardView cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewLayoutNotif);

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.notif_message);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Newacti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title", notificationsModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTitle1());
                    intent.putExtra("body", notificationsModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getBody1());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: save the color in list and show it from there

Comment: How to i do that?

Comment: You can create a variable like boolean isSelected in your NotificationsModel class. Then in OnClick change its value to true. Also in onBindViewHolder, you have to check the value of isSelected and set the color of card accordingly.
    if(notificationsModel.isSelected()){
         //set selected Back ground color for card }
    else
          //set normal background color for card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the flag `IsColorChanged` inside your `notificationsModel` and whenever you are changing the color of `cardview` update the flag in model,

In your `onBindViewHolder` you can add the check as below:

```
if(IsColorChanged){
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}else{
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);// ANY OTHER COLOR
}
```